# CiviCRM support for v5.x

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

I'm using CiviCRM v5.x with PHP 7.2. I would like to know how long would the CiviCRM support end for v5.x or may I get some information about the support terms?

Great thanks for the kind support!

Comment: Hi Stephen - welcome - you may want to read https://civicrm.org/esr which is the only 'offering' of that type. Otherwise many providers would probably upgrade their clients at a minimum for every security release (which is unpredictable but my estimate would be ~ 6 monthly)

Comment: In terms of 'support' not too sure what you might be thinking of, but generally if you go with one of the CiviCRM providers then you would negotiate a support package with them or just work with them on an 'ad hoc' basis

Comment: Got it, thanks for your quick response!